# Visual Basic secondary form slide over main, slide off main, not closing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, userform

I have been creating a Visual Basic Win App for a few different things.
Something I was wanting to add onto it was having the main form in the background, when a side button is clicked, as shown below "Contact", the "Contact" form slides in from the right side of the screen, going left. Once fully on it stops and can be interacted with. This all works.
My problem is that when the "X" button (representing close) is pressed, I want the form to slide off the screen then close instead of remaining open.

I have been able to get the form to slide off the screen. I have also been able to get the form to close. However, I have not been able to get it to slide off the screen then close.
Below are some images of the form, and the code I have for the "X" button on my frmContact form.
I have used a Timer Tick for the animation.
I have already seen that someone else has made something like this using a "DOWN" function with psTimerFunc and piCount, however when I was altering this to try make it suit my application it did not work.
(*I would also just like to mention I have not done much in the way of Visual Basic, and this is me playing around/testing stuff that I can do, any help or tips are appreciated*)

Here is the code for loading the form, when the "X" button is clicked, bringing the form onto the screen "tmrContact_Tick" and then taking the form off the screen (does not work) "tmrContact2":

```
Sub LoadForm(MessageDescription As String)
    Me.Top = 0
    Me.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.BringToFront()
    Me.Show()
    tmrContact.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnX_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnX.Click
    tmrContact2.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub tmrContact_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrContact.Tick
    Me.Left = Me.Left - 5
    If Me.Left + Me.Width <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width + 10 Then
        tmrContact.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tmrContact2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrContact2.Tick
    Do While Me.Left + Me.Width >= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 10
        Me.Left = Me.Left + 1
        Application.DoEvents() ' Allow the application to process other events
    Loop

    tmrContact2.Enabled = False
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

[The Main UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAUl8.png),
[Contact Form when "Contact" is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H40Tt.png)

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the code inline with some advice from user "Jimi" using AnimateWindows. Below is some code I was able to put together and get working, I have manually chosen the starting location of the Contact Form so now when I click open the Contact Form, it does slide onto the screen going from right to left, it isn't very clean, but it will do for now, however when I click the X button, it does not go from left to right, it just closes.
Below is the code:

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class frmContact
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function AnimateWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal time As Integer, ByVal flags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

```
Private Sub frmContact_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AnimateWindow(Me.Handle, 100, &H2)
End Sub

Private Sub btnX_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnX.Click
    AnimateWindow(Me.Handle, 100, &H1)
End Sub
```

End Class

Here is an unlisted YT video link showing the problem in action:
https://youtu.be/ocePY2Dl_SY

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before you apply it to a question. Your VS tags are not applicable and both specific explicitly to NOT use them for code questions. People watch tags for a reason. You are effectively tricking them into reading questions that are irrelevant to them. This is specifically a WinForms question and you didn't add that tag though.

Comment: My apologies sorry. I have never posted on Stack Overflow, and just wanted to try get whatever help I could get. I attached VS as I am using Visual Studio and therefore thought it would be relevant, I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can use the `AnimateWindow` function for this. See here: [How to add custom animations to a ContextMenuStrip?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68728409/7444103). This applies different animations (see the code) to a ContextMenuStrip. You can of course apply the same effects / transitions to any other window (that has a Handle). In the example, you can define the time the animation takes and what kind of effect to apply.  Sliding effects are included

Comment: The `Do While` loop in `tmrContact2` doesn't seem quite right. Wouldn't that run FOREVER...? I would think you'd want something more like `Do While Me.Left <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - 10`.

Comment: Hey Jimi, the AnimateWindow should work perfectly, however I am now getting the problem where instead of the form sliding in on the right side going left until it is on the screen, it simply expands and appears where the button is. I do not think I coded this correctly xD I will update the post with the code I have used.

Comment: Hey Idle_Mind, the same thing happened again, the form appeared but when I clicked the X it just closed on me, it didn't slide off.

Comment: If you want to apply an effect on closing the Form, you have to hide it first, then call `AnimateWindow` (only works on windows that are not shown). Add `AW_ACTIVATE`, otherwise it'll be probably shown underneath other windows. You could also make the button handler async and call `await Task.Delay()` to delay the `Close()` call a bit -- Reading again parts of your question, I'm not sure this function is what you're looking for. It appears you want to **move** the Form to another position, not make it appear with a slide effect, e.g,  `AW_VER_POSITIVE Or AW_HOR_POSITIVE` (appears diagonally)

Comment: Hey Jimi, from testing with the AnimateWindow, yeah it is not entirely what I need/want, I linked a video on the thread showing what it does. Long explanation short, im converting my Excel VBA to Visual Basic so I can make it into an application, I used Group Boxes for pullouts on there, but editing them was difficult, so I wanted to use Forms on here, so when I click on a label for example "Contact" on the right side the Contact Form opens, if that makes sense, and then I can close it. So yes, moving the form to a position, creating a sort of slide animation, not an actual one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on the program all afternoon/evening trying to come up with a solution. Luckily, I was able to figure it out. In the below code, when the Contact Form is loaded, the properties are set with their colours, as well as the positioning/sizing of the form and where it should be in relation to the main form (`frmDDEF`); also, the form is brought to the front and shown with the sliding in animation.

Once "X" is clicked, the form slides off the screen; once off, it is sent to the back and closed. This makes it so that, if the main form is not maximised, without `Me.SendToBack()`, you would be able to see the form sliding still and then closing once it is off the screen; this line of code prevents that.

```
Public Class frmContact

    Public Sub LoadForm(MessageDescription As String)
        grpCONTACTTOP.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(2, 7, 26)
        pnlContact.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(39, 47, 76)
        Me.Top = frmDDEF.Top
        Me.Left = frmDDEF.Left + frmDDEF.Width ' Appears from the right side of the form
        Me.Height = frmDDEF.Height ' Matches the height of Contact with DDEF
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.BringToFront()
        Me.Show()
        tmrContact.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub lblX_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblX.Click
        tmrContact2.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrContact_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrContact.Tick ' Move left
        Me.Left = Me.Left - 5
        If Me.Left + Me.Width <= frmDDEF.Left + frmDDEF.Width + 10 Then
            tmrContact.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrContact2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrContact2.Tick ' Move right
        Me.Left = Me.Left + 5
        If Me.Left >= frmDDEF.Left + frmDDEF.Width Then
            Me.SendToBack()
            tmrContact2.Enabled = False
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```